# What is this white fuzz on my oak tree?

Tags: trees, tree-care, fungus, oak

Do you have any idea what this is on my oak tree?  We are in the middle of a drought in Central Illinois and I've been seeing this on the back of my leaves.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'a a [gall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall) of some kind, though I couldn't tell you which species; I'd guess some species of the gall wasp [Andricus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall_wasp).